# I cannot copy the text style in Microsoft Word using the keyboard shortcut

Tags: ms-office, shortcut, formatting

For years I have used <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy text style in Microsoft Word, and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the style. Recently when I'm in Word (or Excel) and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it always opens my Calendar program (which happens to be BusyCal, though I don't think that's pertinent to this issue). I can copy the style by clicking on the format paintbrush, and then paste the style using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. But can't copy using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I've checked "Customize Keyboard" in MS Word and it shows <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as the shortcut to copy the style. I've checked **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**, no issue there. I've checked Keyboard Maestro, which I use for lots of shortcuts, and nothing is defined in there for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I don't know what else to try. Restarting my Mac seemed to fix the problem for at least one copy and paste of a style, but then it goes back to opening my calendar (and often creating an event with the text I had copied!). The issue occurs in Word & Excel, but not in PowerPoint.

Help! I use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut a hundred times a day!

Comment: Have you checked BusyCal's preferences for any shortcuts? Also, can you archive BusyCal (thus making it non-executable anymore) to see if that helps? Alternatively, can you try to delete and reset the shortcuts in Word and Excel?

Comment: That's strange. You seem to have checked out all the usual suspects. This should not normally cause a problem but Command+Shift+C is also a keyboard shortcut in BusyCal which you said gets opened from Word. Maybe disabling that shortcut in BusyCal, if possible, might help.

Comment: Yes, Command+Shift+C copies format in BusyCal, but it's a built in shortcut and I can find no way to disable it. What's strange is that Command+Shift+C only opens BusyCal when I'm in Word or Excel and not in any other program. For that reason I think it may be a Microsoft Office issue. However, Command+Shift+C works fine in PowerPoint and copies the format as intended.